# test if a specific key was used to sign an .apk file

Tags: android, apk, private-key

I have a .key file and a signed .apk file (android phongap application built using phonegap build).

How can I check if the .apk was signed using that key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve and compare the fingerprints of the public keys included in the apk file and your key file.

For the apk:

1. Unpack the file `/META-INF/CERT.RSA` from the apk.
2. Use `keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA` to compute the SHA1 + MD5 fingerprints.

For the key file:

1. Run `keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore file> -alias <key alias>`.
2. Input your keystore password.
3. This will output the SHA1 + MD5 fingerprints. If you omit the `-v` only the MD5 fingerprint will be printed.

Comment: thanks, I did not eventually get to test this but it sounds just like what I asked for.